# What is the English word for just appearing to be dead

Tags: single-word-requests

There is the unfortunate medical condition of just appearing to be dead, and some times the condition had fatal consequences. What is the English expression for the condition.

Answer (score 4):

This condition is called *catalepsy*.

> Catalepsy is a medical condition in which one appears to be dead but actually not dead. Even doctors may not identify the condition whether the patient is dead or alive. They think that the person is dead.

[Business Insider](https://amp.businessinsider.com/catalepsy-is-a-condition-that-makes-you-look-like-you-are-dead-2018-1#referrer=https://www.google.com&aoh=15744882662027&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s)

Comment: I tidied up your link for you so you could see how it is done. Please feel free to roll back.

Comment: @NigelJ When I tidy links, I like to remove unnecessary fields, like "referrer=" here.

Answer (score 1):

Catalepsy is incorrect. The condition described in **NOT** catalepsy nor catatonia, neither of which mimic clinical death.

The condition described is Locked-In Syndrome, in which the only apparent sign of life is eye blinking, but sometimes not even that.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5183991/

Comment: There sadly appear to be more than one condition/s where a living patient may be wrongly identified as being dead, even by doctors. The one you mention is even harder to spot.

Comment: Catatonia is a psychological condition. Catalepsy is a physical condition.

Comment: Edwin, "harder to spot," suggests even more likely to be mistaken for a corpse, and I should say that next to being a corpse, being mistaken for one is the deadliest, not to mention the most embarrassing state to be in.  Since no word seems to meet the OP's exact criterion, we have the chance to make a new contribution to the medical lexicon:  pseudoptoma.

Comment: It is interesting that there is not a term which exactly corresponds with what I asked for, as the phenomenon is well attested from history. Some legislations as in Norway at the end of the nineteenth century even took precautions to postpone burial till after 72 hours had elapsed.